# Двумерные массивы и их инициализация.

Tags: c

Представим я инициализирую двумерный массив:

```
double name[2][2];
```

И у меня есть процедура для его распечатки;
Имеет она такой вывод:
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 . Вразве он не должен получить случайное значение? Почему он инициализируется нулем, если я не применял никаких классов хранения? Одномерный ,например, получает случайные значения.

Comment: Одномерный тоже должен инициализироваться нулями, если он глобальный.

Comment: Вот сейчас еще сделал эксперимент. Если объявить глобальный массив размером пару гигабайт, то при запуске программы эта память реально не резервируется. Наверное, используется страничная переадресация. При обращении к любому участку массива там нули. Видимо, заполнение нулями происходит при обращении, потому заодно и нет задержки при запуске. Когда я пытаюсь заполнить весь массив нулями вручную, видно, что программа съедает запрошенную память, и заполнение происходит не мгновенно.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, интуитивно вы пытаетесь угадать как работает алокатор памяти внутри библиотеки Си и ядра. Если говорить конкретно о Linux kernel, то там есть одна страничка только на чтение, которая заполнена 0. Реальное выделение происходит по алгоритму COW.

Comment: @0andriy, спасибо, это все объясняет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, в вашем примере объявления вы никак *не инициализируете* массив.

Во-вторых, будет ли массив, объявленный без явного инициализатора как-то инициализироваться сам по себе, зависит от того контекста, в котором он объявлен. Этот контекст будет определять класс хранения вашего объекта, даже если вы и не "применяли никаких классов хранения" явно. Вы же никакого контекста не привели.

Итак

- Объект с автоматической классом хранения (переменная, определенная в блоке) будет изначально содержать непредсказуемые значения.
- Объект со статическим классом хранения (напр., переменная, определенная на уровне файла) будет инициализирован нулями.
- Объект, являющийся частью агрегата (поле структуры, элемент массива), инициализируется так, как инициализируется сам охватывающий агрегат.

В-третьих, если объект не инициализируется, это совсем не означает, что он обязан получать какие-то "страшные" значения. Чисто вследствие стечения обстоятельств ваш неинициализированный объект может оказаться заполненным нулями. Ноль - такое же непредсказуемое значение, как и любое другое непредсказуемое значение.

Более того, никто не запрещает конкретной реализации обнулять все переменные без исключения (каким бы способом это ни делалось). С точки зрения языка неинициализированный объект все равно будет содержать непредсказуемые значения. (Имейте также в виду, что такое непредсказуемое значение не только непредсказуемо само по себе, но также и не обладает гарантией стабильности: последовательные чтения неинициализированного объекта могут "видеть" в нем разные значения.)

Двумерность вашего массива, как таковая, тут никакой роли не играет.